# Hosting OSM Vector Tile Server using ubuntu

Tags: apache, gis, openstreetmap, ubuntu-18.04

Here what am **looking for**,

Am trying to **host my own vector tile server**,
Here is an image for the kind of Map I want on some pages it is named as a "positron" not opensourced, even a similar kind of it can also work with me.
[image: Positron/Similar GrayScale Map]

Reference link for the style.json that we found [Positron Style Json](https://github.com/openmaptiles/positron-gl-style)
Inside style.json they have induced links of MapTiler Keys that were open-sourced but they removed this in February, there is no alternative we found on how we should run this on frontend.
style.json snippet

```json
  "sources": {
    "openmaptiles": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/v3/tiles.json?key={key}"
    }
  },
  "sprite": "https://openmaptiles.github.io/positron-gl-style/sprite",
  "glyphs": "https://api.maptiler.com/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf?key={key}",
```

Initially, when I started I was not much aware of the difference between vector tile and raster tiles

I followed this link and build the server[OSM Tile Server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/), it was working very good but it was native and I was looking for the kind of above design I have linked above. The native raster tiles look like this [OSM Tile View](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/21.843/82.795), we are not actually looking for this

For the installation of PBF file we followed this planet.osm link and installed them with Postgress Database [Planet OSM file used](https://planet.openstreetmap.org/)

Soon we realized we need to host a vector tile server rather than a raster one as they are providing images and we are not looking for this kind of design. As there is no-installation I found for the vector tile server on the main switch2OSM maps website.

I went through this link [OSM Vector Tile Server](https://github.com/geofabrik/openstreetmap-carto-vector-tiles) Now when we are installing them [ReadMe file](https://github.com/geofabrik/openstreetmap-carto-vector-tiles/blob/master/README_VECTOR_TILES.md) "tessera" they are deprecated and also removed their support from the back. Now even the raster Tile server has stopped working.

Now I don't know what mistake am doing or what step I should take now, our usage is cumbersome and we want to host our own vector tile server to reduce the cost.

Any reference or guidance will be really appreciated.

**Note: Tech Stack we are using**

- Frontend: VueJS
- Backend: GeoDjango

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming question as outlined in [help/on-topic] to me... Can you edit it to make it match Stackoverflow's on-topic criteria (e.g. be a lot more specific, ask about programming issues, not hosting)? Otherwise, stackoverflow is the wrong place for this question

Answer (score 0):

if anyone gets stuck at the same position where have been with switch2OSM and looking to build their own vector tile server.

Please use this link named [OpenMapTiles](https://openmaptiles.com/server/)

I wasn't aware at the start therefore it took some time to figure it out.

Also thanks to OpenStreetMaps Telegram Community.